# How to read values from this file

Tags: c++, file-io

So i have [this file](http://pastebin.com/YbG7ABSb) and this code:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("fonts.dat", "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
        return 1;

    char readLineBuffer[200];

    if(readLineBuffer == NULL) { return 1; }
    if(readLineBuffer == 0) { return 1; }

    while (fgets(readLineBuffer, 200, file) != NULL)
    {
        readLineBuffer[strcspn(readLineBuffer, "\n")] = '\0';
        //if (readLineBuffer[0] == '\0' || readLineBuffer[0] == '#') {continue;}
        for(int i=0; readLineBuffer[i]!=00; i++)
        {
            if (readLineBuffer[i]=='#')
            {
                readLineBuffer[i] = 00;
                break;
            }
        }
        puts(readLineBuffer);
    }

    fclose(file);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

It removes the comment lines starting with `#`.

But how can I read from that file like [FONT_ID] and store it into a variable for using in other code?

Comment: do you know about {io|f}stream in c++?

Comment: It's a text file, so you should not open it in binary mode. There are also better ways to find the `'#'` in the line you just read (see e.g. [`std::strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr) if you want to continue with C only functions). And since you're on Windows you should be careful to make sure the newline isn't actually the Windows newline (`"\r\n"`).

Comment: thanks for the tip, but how do i read them id tags?

Comment: How about [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)? Or use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and just do a normal [comparision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

Comment: but how do i take the id on the next line into some variable in code?
i'm kinda new to this...

Comment: Or just use [the right tool](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/) for the task.

Comment: well that doesnt really work without modifying the dat file i guess.
but it looks good, will give it a try soon.

Comment: it dint work. so i still need to manually read the file. but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on in this code that suggests you're having a hard time getting to grips with C/C++, or that you have been learning bad habbits from other programmers/languages.

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("fonts.dat", "rb");
```

Try, whenever possible, to avoid separating the declaration and the assignment. You said this is a text file, so you don't need to open it in "binary" mode. Reading in binary means you're going to have to worry about the different end-of-line types. Open it in text mode and the operating system/libc will do translation for you so that end-of-lines are magically just "\n" like they should be.

```
char readLineBuffer[200];

if(readLineBuffer == NULL) { return 1; }
if(readLineBuffer == 0) { return 1; }
```

Firstly, one of the advantages of using fixed-sized storage the way you just did is that it can never evaluate to NULL. You only need null checks when working with pointers. While it's true that - under the hood - "readLineBuffer" can be used as a pointer, it is also an array. Try the following simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char buffer[1234];
    char* bufPointer = buffer; // yes, it looks like a pointer.
    printf("the size of buffer is %u but the size of bufPointer is %u\n",
           sizeof(buffer),
           sizeof(bufPointer));
    return 0;
}
```

Secondly, "NULL" is simply a #define

```
#define NULL 0
```

(which is why in C++11 they added the special 'nullptr' constant).

```
while (fgets(readLineBuffer, 200, file) != NULL)
```

Manually repeating the sizes of things is dangerous. Use the "sizeof()" command

```
while (fgets(readLineBuffer, sizeof(readLineBuffer), file)
```

Are you certain that none of the lines in the file exceed 200 bytes in length? Imagine the following:

```
fgets(buffer, 20, file);
```

Now imagine the line:

123456789012345678#this is the comment

The fgets will read "123456789012345678#" and your code would remove the trailing '#' and do a "puts" which would write a "123456789012345678\n" to the file. Then you would read "this is the comment", not find a comment character, and write a new line "this is the comment\n" to the file.

Secondly, since you are going to iterate the line anyway, you might want to consider either:

a. iterate the buffer yourself
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(readLineBuffer) && i[0] != '\0')
    {
        if(readLineBuffer[i] == '\n' || readLineBuffer[i] == '#')
        {
          readLineBuffer[i] = 0;
          break;
        }
    }

b. use strpbrk
    char* eol = strpbrk("#\n", readLineBuffer);
    if ( eol != NULL ) // found comment or end of line
        *eol = '\0';

This would reduce your code to the following. While this code would compile on a "C++" compiler, it is pretty much pure "C".

```
FILE *file = fopen("fonts.dat", "r");
if (file == NULL)
    return 1;

char readLineBuffer[200];
while (fgets(readLineBuffer, sizeof(readLineBuffer), file) != NULL)
{
    // find comment or end of line so we can truncate the line.
    char* eol = strpbrk(readLineBuffer, "#\n");
    if ( eol != NULL )
        *eol = '\0';
    puts(readLineBuffer);
}

fclose(file);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

If you want to process and store the actual information that's going by, you're going to need to create variables to store it, code to inspect/"parse? each line in readLineBuffer as it goes past, and you're going to want to learn to use commands like "sscanf", "atoi", "strtoul", and ultimately you're going to need to create some miniature kind of state machine.

Alternatively, you might want to look into a scripting language like "Perl" or "Python" which are designed for tasks like this.

```
# perl version

local $/ = /\n{2,}/;  # Read the file as paragraphs.
open(file, "font.dat") || die "Can't open font.dat";
my %data = ();
while ($line = <>) {
    $line =~ s/\s+#.*$//mg;    # Get rid of all the comments.
    $line =~ s/\n\n/\n/sg;     # Fix any blank lines we introduced.

    # Each data block starts with an ini-style label, that is a
    # line starting with a "[", followed by some word-characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9)
    # and a closing "]", maybe with some whitespace after that.

    # Try to remove a label line, capturing the label, or skip this block.
    next unless $line =~ s/^ \[ (\w+) \] \s* \n+ //sx;

    # Store the remaining text into data indexed on the label.
    my ($label) = ($1);  # the capture
    $data{$label} = $line;
}

print("FONT_ID = $data{'FONT_ID'}\n");
```

Or written in perlier-perl

```
local $/ = /\n{2,}/;  # Read blocks separated by 2-or-more newlines (paragraphs)
die "Can't open file" unless open(file, "font.dat");
while (<>) {
    s/\s+#.*$//mg;
    s/\n{2,}/\n/sg;
    $data{$1} = $_ if (s/^\[(\w+)\][^\n]+\n+//s);
}
$fontId = ;
print("font_id = ", int($data{'FONT_ID'}), "\n");
```

Comment: Great info! Thank you for this great text you have written. I'm really beginner on c and c++ and just read some tutorials and write code based on them. Thanks again!

Comment: Having a scripting handy language - javascript, perl, python, etc - is great for helping you solve the gnarly, big-picture parts of problems; "C" will force you to focus on the practical, computational parts of problems you need to know when you need speed/performance.

Writing C code while learning C++ is a trap. C++ and object-oriented code is really about describing the problems, patterns and features of the program discretely. C# is actually a reasonable way to learn the OOP side of things, just be aware that good C# does things that would be very bad in C++ :)